# Is there a cohomology theory wider than crystalline?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, crystalline-cohomology

We know crystalline cohomology is calculated by taking an inverse limit:

$$H_{cris}^i:=\varprojlim_nH_{cris}^i(X/W_n(k))$$

provided $X$ projective smooth over a perfect field $k$ of char $p$.

I want to ask, is there a wider cohomology theory that can calculate the crystalline cohomology directly (without taking the limit)?

Since pro-$\mathrm{\acute etale}$ cohomology generalizes $\mathbb Q_\ell$-cohomology, so I wonder if there is also a such thing for cris.

Could you provide references or give some reasons why it's difficult to generalize (if it doesn't exist)?

Thanks.

Comment: Crossposted at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651875/is-there-a-cohomology-theory-wider-than-crystalline

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted.

Comment: If some question should be closed, it's the one on MSE. This question is surely research-level.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks. I have deleted it.

Comment: In the definition of the crystalline site, there are some nilpotent PD thickenings around. If you replace those by $p$-complete PD thickenings (so that modulo every $p^n$ you get a nilpotent PD thickening as before), you get a site that directly computes the limit over $n$ of crystalline cohomology modulo $p^n$. Is that what you are asking?